# pulling ranom index array from a different class

Tags: arrays, class, random, indexing

Trying to make a mad lib that will pull a random Verb from an array in my other class, tried creating an object of other class and calling the `getRandomVerb()` method inserting the array list, works normally for the main class and arrays in main but having trouble with other class.

[Example 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdvdt.png)
 [Example 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuS0H.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review the welcome tutorial for SO, and [How to ask...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) along with [creating a minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've tried to ch.getRandomVerb(List <String> verbs);